# Spring not injecting test bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, autowired

In SpringBoot test, **DataSourceHandler** is created in **AppTestCfg** but **DataSource** is created in **AppCfg**. Why are they not both created in **AppTestCfg**?

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class AppCfg {
    @Bean
    public DataSourceHandler getDataSourceHandler(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceHandler(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getSource(DataSourceProps props) {
         // create data source
    }
}
@Configuration
public class AppTestCfg extends AppCfg {
    @Bean
    public DataSourceHandler getDataSourceHandler(){
        return new MockDataSourceHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getSource(){
        return null;
    }
}
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppTestCfg.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataSourceProps.class})
public class AppTest {
    // tests
}
```

If I change the signature of **getSource** in **AppTestCfg** as follows, both **DataSource** and **DataSourceHandler** are created using **AppTestCfg**

```
@Bean
public DataSource getSource(DataSourceProps props){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not take advantage of Spring Boot's `@MockBean` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppTestCfg.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataSourceProps.class})
public class AppTest {

    @MockBean
    private DataSource dataSourceStub;
}
```

This will replace any occurences of any beans of that interface in the application context and replace them with a mock.

Comment: hi, @Maciej Kowalski i replaced the @Bean with `@MockBean
    public DataSourceHandler getDataSourceHandler = new MockDataSourceHandler();` but there is an error 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
`.
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appTestCfg': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/Answers
`.
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/Answers`

Comment: you need mockito-core in your classpath

Comment: i get this error `Mockito cannot mock this class: interface javax.sql.DataSource.
`

Answer (score 0):

It's because the object types of the Beans are the same.

If you want two beans of the same type, you have to specify different named beans. Try being specific about the name of the new bean:

```
@Configuration
public class AppTestCfg extends AppCfg {
    @Bean(name="secondDataSourceHandler")
    public DataSourceHandler getMockDataSourceHandler(){
        return new MockDataSourceHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getSource(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, @Kieveli I would like to replace data source with a mock object